# passlib and Google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, import, libraries

I downloaded the Python library passlib and i am trying to use the sha256_crypt class to encrypt and decode data.

I included it in the `app.yaml` file but it says `the library "passlib" is not supported`.

I can't use it? If so what should I use instead?

Furthermore, is there a limitation on the libraries you can use with GAP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add that module to the libraries in the app.yaml.

Yo just need to upload the modules along with your code. For that, instead of installing the module (with pip, easy_install, apt-get, etc.), you copy/decompress it in your project folder.

Why don't you use instead Pycrypto, which is supported as a [third party library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27) and is written in C.

Regarding the last question, there are some limitation of what libraries can be run in Appengine. Currently no user provided modules with C extensions are supported, some are supported via the [third party libraries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27). Additionally some system calls are disabled for security, so that can also prevents the use of some modules.